# Integral and constant variable a b and c solve equation.

Tags: calculus, integration

I think this is a relatively simple problem to solve but I'm not too sure/that great at it. I was given this:

Say that $$X=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\cos x}{(x+2)^2} dx$$

and

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin y\cos y}{y+1}dy=aX+\frac{b}{\pi+2}+c$$

Then what is the value of $$100a+50b+4c$$ given that $a,b,c$ are constants.

Thank you if someone wants to try and solve this.

Comment: Are u asking what is $100a+50b+4c$ in term of $X$? That is not an equation...

Comment: I think this means that, $a$ is multiplied by all of integral $X$.

Comment: I also think there is some way to solve for a, b, and c to implement into the final equation. But I do not know, that's why I am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$Y=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin y\cos y}{y+1} dy = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin 2y}{2 (y+1)} dy $$ We then use $x=2y \implies dy=\frac{dx}{2} $. We then have, $$Y=\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\sin x}{2(x+2)} dx $$ Integrating by parts, keeping $u=\frac {1}{x+2} $ and $v'=\sin x $,we get, $$Y=\frac {1}{2}[\frac {-\cos x}{x+2}]^{\pi}_{0} -\frac {1}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi}(-\cos x)(-\frac{1}{(x+2)^2}) dx $$ $$\implies Y=\frac {1}{2}[\frac {1}{\pi+2}+\frac {1}{2}]-\frac {X}{2} =-\frac {1}{2}X+\frac {1}{2 (\pi +2)}+\frac {1}{4} $$

Comparing, we can see that $a=\frac{-1}{2},b=\frac{1}{2},c=\frac{1}{4}$ giving us $$\boxed{100a+50b+4c=-24}$$

Comment: Thank you. You don't have to, but do you mind if you continue? Sorry if I am sounding pushy. Thanks for explaining some of this.

Comment: Thank you for continuing. I believe this is correct. You have explained a lot. Thanks for that. Now I understand how the integrals correlates/compares to finding a, b and c. I initially thought there was a little bit more to do before the comparison. But you have answered my question. Thank you.